# Entity Framework: Como realizar o insert de uma tabela com relação 1..n sem que os filhos também sejam inseridos?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Estou utilizando Dotnet Core 3.1 com EF Core.
Possuo três classes em meu contexto:

```
public class Sale
{
    public Sale()
    {
        this.Cars = new List<Car>();
        this.CarSeller = new Seller();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ProcessStatusEnum Status { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Seller CarSeller { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

}

public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Year { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Fabrication { get; set; }
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }

}

 public class Seller
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

A minha dúvida está ocorrendo quando tento inserir uma nova venda:

```
 public ActionResult<int> SaveVehicleSale(SaleDTO newSale)
    {
        try
        {
            newSale.Id = 0;
            newSale.Status = ProcessStatusEnum.ConfirmingPayment;

            if (Functions.IsAnyNullOrEmpty(newSale))
                new ApiException(StatusCodeEnum.BadRequest, MsgException.ObjectAtributeNull);

            _context.Sale.Add(ConvertType.To(newSale)); //Converte o SaleDTO para o Sale
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return _apiResponse.ResponseRet<int>(StatusCodeEnum.OK, newSale.Id);
        }
        catch (ApiException e)
        {
            return _apiResponse.ResponseRet<int>(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return _apiResponse.ResponseRetWithoutEnumerable(e);
        }
    }
```

Ao inserir, ele também está tentando adicionar um novo Carro. Como faço para ele apenas referenciar um carro já existente? Isso já ocorre com a Classe Seller, mas não sei como fazer isso com um tipo List<>.

Agradeço muito, desde já!

Comment: se Carro já existe, pode recuperar para que o EF tenha track disso: algo assim (vou fazer o exemplo como se fosse um objeto só): `newSale.Carro = carroContext.Get(newSale.Carro.Id)`

Comment: Entendi. Irei tentar isso daqui a pouco, obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!

Comment: @RicardoPontual posta essa resposta para não deixarmos essa pergunta em aberto

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa informar ao EF que o(s) carro(s) já existe(m) (dar um tracking no EF). Você deve atribuir os carros na lista `public virtual List<Car> Cars { get; set; }` da classe Sale.